# programm NFC Card inside the phone Android and Ios

Tags: android, ios, nfc

we have a printer in our work and this printer have card reader to identify the user who is printing using the card , now we have an app for ios and android . we want to replace the card with our app , can i make the app have a function like the card  i mean user can go to the card scanner and use the nfc in the phone , can i do just same as the QR code ,

so basically the app will generate a card inside the app and the card scanner in the printer can read it from our phone , is this possible for ios and android

Comment: You cannot do this with iOS.  You can only read NFC tags, you cannot perform card emulation.

Comment: what about android , can i perform card emulation

Comment: I think you can, but I don't know anything specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host Card Emulation (HCE) is not currently possible on iOS.
It is possible on Android, I'm not experienced with Android development so I can't give any help on the programming side of things other than to point you to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce).

Note: it has limitations for copying/cloning arbitrary cards.

See [this answer by Michael Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848318)

> 1. Many access control systems use the card ID (UID) to identify the card (or even to make an access control desicion!). With Android HCE, an app cannot set the emulated card ID.
> 2. Many access control systems use cards/acces tokes that are not based on ISO 14443-4 (ISO-DEP) + ISO 7816-4 smartcard protocol. With Android HCE an app can only emulate smartcard applications that use ISO 7816-4 APDUs and application structure.
> 3. Even if the access control system does not use the card ID and uses an ISO 7816-4 smartcard application, it is very likely that the card contains some cryptographic secret (secret key) that cannot be extracted from the card through smartcard commands.

Another option worth considering is using an NFC enabled wallet passes for both Android and iOS. It's a good bit more complicated but it's end product is quite similar. At [PassNinja](http://passninja.com/) we are trying to make the process of creating, distributing and reading NFC mobile wallet passes easier.

Disclaimer: I work for [Flomio](https://flomio.com/), the company behind PassNinja.