# Is there a software that can change NFC Tag's serial number?

Tags: tags, nfc, uniqueidentifier, mifare, serial-number

I ordered a bunch of NFC tags from a Chinese supplier (I know, red flags) with the promise that they will serialize my tags as instructed so it will work w/ our software and avoid serial duplicates. (Our software uses the tags' serial numbers, not the content.)

Now the thousands of NFC tags arrived and it seems they have disregarded the proper serialization, and worst, half of the darn thing are duplicates (completely unusuable for our purpose!)

So now I'm in a hole :(

So is there a software that can change NFC Tag's serial number?

Tag chip is NTAG203

Comment: It may be possible, but you have to tell us exactly what tag it is. Link to datasheet may be helpful as well.

Comment: it's an Chip: Ntag 203

Comment: Is there a possibility to get UID changeable NTags, like the UID changeable Milfare NFC Cards?

Answer (score 5):

No, the anti-collision identifier (UID, "serial number") of genuine NTAG203 chips cannot be changed. That serial number is permanently burned in during the manufacturing process. However, there are tags available (typically from Chinese suppliers) that behave similar to MIFARE Ultralight (and derivates like NTAG203) and permit changing the UID using special commands.

Note that genuine NTAG203 chips never have duplicate UIDs. If manufactured by NXP, they always have unique IDs. So if you encountered duplicates, its likely that those are counterfeit tags.

Comment: What about NTAG213? @Michael Roland

Comment: @c-an Same thing.