# Read UID of Nfc tag even if there is no NDEF record Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, nfc, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a requirement that is similar to simple access control or employee ID on my Windows 10 Mobile app. If I have an Nfc tag, I want to be able to scan the tag and get a unique ID, or in this case the serial number or UID of the tag.

As I understand it, the UID is burned into the chip and cannot be written over. Whereas the NDEF records could be written to. Also, I want this to be simple, so if I order tags and they are blank, meaning no NDEF records, that is okay since I don't want to use NDEF anyway. I want to just be able to scan the tag and get the UID.

I can then associate the UID of the tag to an employee record and I will have access control that way that cannot be changed or written over or duplicated like NDEF could.

I have done a ton of reading and looked at the Microsoft Universal samples on GitHub for Nfc but most use NDEF.

Thanks!

Comment: With regard to using the UID for access control and your assumption that it cannot be changed/written/duplicated, you might want to read [Serials on NFC Tags - truly unique? cloneable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21700718/2425802) and [How do NFC tags prevent copying?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/63483/47234).

Comment: I stand corrected, I am sure that with anything, it can be hacked as is evident in the links you sent. That said, I think what I should have said or meant to say is that it certainly is not as easy as if I were using NDEF. In other words, if I were using NDEF, it is VERY easy to read the data and then write (duplicate) the data onto other tags. At least with using UID, somebody would have to go through a bit more effort to duplicate that (ie buying tools and tags made for cloning this and having the skillset to do so). But, my original question still stands. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use PCSC from smartcardreader class in UWP. It supports both contactless card (including NFC) and contact card (smart card).

The sample is here. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Nfc.

I used to read raw content in Mifare card so I'm sure you can read UID using this.